# How to pair items in Python and push them in array inside another array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm sending a pair of numbers as part of a POST request that looks something like this: `/updateDB?id=001&numbers=1,2,3,4,5,6`

On the server side in Python, I am getting these parameters using:

```
objectID = request.args.get('id')
myNumbers = request.args.get('numbers')
```

I want to pair these numbers and place them into their individual arrays, and then place those arrays inside another array.

For example, I want to pair 1 and 2, 3 and 4, and 5 and 6 and place them into their own arrays (so 3 arrays in total). Once that is done, I want to place those 3 arrays into another array.

```
[
  [1,2]
  [3,4]
  [5,6]
]
```

I tried writing a for loop to go through `myNumbers`:

```
for x in myNumbers:
    print myNumbers(x)
```

But I get the error that `unicode object is not callable`. I'm guessing this is because there are commas between the numbers?

Comment: I think you meant `GET` request there. Anyways, the error is because you are trying to iterate over a `string` unicode object. You can split the `args` like `request.args.get('numbers').split(',')`

Comment: @kiran.koduru Thanks, I'm looking into it.

Comment: @kiran.koduru Unrelated, but shouldn't I use POST when sending data the database?

Comment: yes. POST should be used for sending data but from your answer I think it looks like it says `request.args.GET`. The `GET` refers to the URL parameters attached to the URL. You should create a `<form>` and add `<input type="text">` fields to pass the elements via post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[list(pair) for pair in zip(myNumbers[::2], myNumbers[1::2])]
```

Will result in the structure you are looking for

Comment: This is a great method but it converts the numbers into strings? Probably because the numbers are being sent as strings.

Comment: @maprYour myNumbers is most probably a string. Check `type(myNumbers)`. If its a string such as "1,2,3,4,5,6", you have to split it by `myNumbers.split(',')` will generate an array of strings i.e ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]. To get an int array you have to map them to an int for eg `map(int, myNumbers.split(','))` and then use the method in this answer

Comment: They are being sent as unicode so that ends up adding a `u` in front of the numbers as well, like this: [ [u'1',u'2'], [u'3',u'4'], [u'5',u'6'] ]. I will try the method you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

here is sample for Python 3:

```
def pair_list(original_list):
    new_big_list=[]
    for i in range(0,len(original_list)-1, 2):
        new_big_list.append([original_list[i],original_list[i+1]])
    return new_big_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    print(pair_list(test_list))
```

the output will be:
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

change range to xrange if you are in Python 2.7

Comment: Because the numbers are being sent as strings, how can I make sure they are int() or float() once the output is complete?

Comment: I believe it works for string, int and float. doesn't matter data type.